# Add value to one object in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a function:

```
public void Add(User user)            
{
    var id = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
    //add id to FK CUserID 
    context.User.Add(user); 
}
```

I'm adding user data to database. How to add id value to CUserID?

```
public class User
{
    [key]    
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string E-mail { get; set; }

    public UserProfile CUserID { get; set; }

}

public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CUserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT:
If I try do:

```
user.CUserId = id;
```

I get an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'Project.Models.UserProfile'

Comment: Could you add the types to the properties in `User`? It looks like `CUserID` is a `UserProfile`, not an integer. I assume `WebSecurity.CurrentUserId` is an integer?

Comment: `CUserID` is a `userProfile` and `WebSecurity.CurrentUserId` is an integer. How fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `User` class:

```
public class User
{
    [key]    
    int UserID { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Surname { get; set; }
    string E-mail { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserProfile)]
    int CUserID { get; set; }
    virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; ]
}
```

Now you can set the `ID` value and entity framework will get the matching `UserProfile` when you save changes.

Comment: I update `User` class. I don't wrote it correct here. I have `public UserProfile CUserID {get; set;}`. I'm using code first so I don't need to write `[Foreginkay("UserProfile")]`. I had wrong `User` class, sorry for mistake. If I have current correct class, I must write `virtual UserProfile UserProfile {get;set;}` ?

Comment: I would make an integer of `CUserID` because an ID usually is some primitive type. The new `UserProfile` property together with `CUserID` is a _foreign key association_. You have to use the `ForeignKey` attribute (which is OK with code first) or use fluent mapping to tell EF that both properties belong to the same association.

Comment: I do it like you wrote. After change, I used migration. During update-database I get an error: `The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.User_dbo.UserProfile_CUserId". The conflict occurred in database "db_wydarzenia", table "dbo.UserProfile", column 'CUserId'.`

Answer (score 0):

Going on what you've described in your question, try this:

```
public void Add(User user)
{
    using (var context = new MyDbContext())
    {
        var currentUser = context.UserProfile.Single(
            u => u.UserName == System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);

        var newUser = new User();
        newUser.Name = user.Name;
        newUser.Surname = user.Surname;
        newUser.Email = user.Email;
        newUser.CUserID = currentUser.CUserId;

        context.User.Add(newUser);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```